# If the index $n$ of a normal subgroup $K$ is finite, then $g^n\in K$ for each $g$ in the group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K \unlhd G$ be a normal subgroup of some group $G$ and let $|G/K|=n<\infty$. I want to show that $g^n\in K$ for all $g\in G$.

Let $g\in G$, if $g\in K$, then $g^n\in K$ and we are done. If $g^n\notin K$ then consider the set of left cosets
$$
C=\{K, gK,g^2K,...,g^{n-1}K\}
$$
I want to show that these cosets are all disjoint and hence $C=K$, then I want to show that $g^nK=K$, so $g^n\in K$. 
Suppose
$$
g^lK=g^mK
$$
for some $m,l<n$, then $g^{m-l}\in K$. I am not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: Note the same questions, but it is answered there: [Powers of elements and subgroups](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150163/powers-of-elements-and-subgroups)

Comment: This seems to be basically the same question: [Prove that if a normal subgroup $H$ of $ G$ has index $n$, then $g^n \in H$ for all $g \in G$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472672/prove-that-if-a-normal-subgroup-h-of-g-has-index-n-then-gn-in-h-for)

Comment: If normality is not assumed, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108952/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the canonical projection $\pi : G \to G/K$. We know $G/K$ is a finite group of order $n$ by assumption. Thus $\pi(g)^n = \pi(g^n) = 1$ in $G/K$, i.e. back in $G$ we have $g^n \in K$. Done.

Answer (score 8):

Although, I think it is duplicate, you can use this fact that: $$[G:K]=n\longrightarrow \forall g\in G, (gK)^n=K\iff g^nK=K\iff g^n\in K$$

Comment: Nice suggestion! +1

Comment: Hello, Babak! I've missed you! ;-)

Comment: Babak, are you okay? I've been worried about you...is it your internet again that's getting in your way?

Comment: I was just worried, since you hadn't posted. I hope your trip went well! Welcome HOME!

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy for your charming words. :-)

Comment: "Meeting" you online each day warms my heart. You're always welcome, dear Babak!

Comment: welcome back dear friend!

Comment: @B.S. Nice hint!

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to go that far. Since you know that $|G/K|=n<\infty$ and 
$G/K =\{K, gK,g^2K,...,g^{n-1}K\}$. Then for any $gK$ in $G/K$, $(gK)^n= g^nK=K $ which answers your question