# A normal subgroup $H$ of $G$, $[G:H] = n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H\triangleleft G$, and H is a subgroup of G such that $[G:H] = k$, where $[G:H]$ states the number of left cosets of $H$ in $G$.

1) How may I show that for all $a\in G, a^k\in H$?

2) If we do NOT assume the normality of $H$, can I have any counterexample showing that 1) is not true?

Comment: Oh, I meant "of the index $[G:H]$".

Comment: One typically says "is a subgroup of index $k$", without the "the".

Comment: @DietrichBurde The last correction may help you clarify...?

Comment: Oh, I got it....@DanielFischer

Comment: Concerning question 2), look at the smallest group having a non-normal subgroup. Look at a non-normal subgroup of that.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472672, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510023

Comment: @Watson Ah, this is the one I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, $[G:H]=k$, then the order of $G/H$ is $k$ and $\bar a^k=1$ where $\bar a$ is the class of $a$ in $G/H$ and $a^k\in H$, since its class in $G/H$ is $1$.